# Skip_callbacks - Not working Rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, ruby-on-rails-5

I am upgrading Rails from 4 to 5 version. From one of my Model say entity model I am using Skip_callbacks for one method in after_create of the model, but still method is getting called which raises errors on save though skip_callbacks set to true

entity.rb

```
class Entity< ActiveRecord::Base

  after_create :method, unless: :skip_callbacks

  def method
  #some code here
  end

end
```

myspec_spec.rb

```
describe test do
 before :each do
  #some code here
  @entity.save! skip_callbacks: true
 end
end
```

Any suggestions will help me a lot for this issue.

Comment: How about always using singular or always using plural in `callback`? Also, maybe provide an `attr_accessor` for `skip_callbacks`

Comment: Sorry I made a mistake in my code in my model it is skip_callbacks only, have updated in my code.

Comment: See updated comment please

Comment: Also I have already set attr_accessor :skip_callbacks

Comment: try to place `@entity.skip_callbacks = true` before `@entity.save!`

Answer (score 8):

Rails 4

```
Survey.skip_callback(:save, :before, :calculate_average)
```

Rails 5

```
Survey.skip_callback(:save, :before, :calculate_average, raise: false)
```

https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_bot/issues/931